# Invalid typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't figure out why this function thinks a `)` is missing from the end. When I do place the `)` it creates a self executing function and generates javascript that *isnt* what I want.

Works

```
this.Events.off = (): any {
    var events = arguments[0],
        callback = arguments[1];
    if (typeof events === 'string' && typeof callback === 'function') {
        this._events.off.call(this._events, events, callback);
    }
    else if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        this._events.off.call(this._events, callback);
    }
};
```

Errors

```
declare var $, Backbone;

export class WebControls {

    _events;
    Events;

    constructor (options? ) {

        this._events = $.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

        this.Events = {};

        this.Events.on = (events: string, cb: (event: any) => any) {
            this._events.on.apply(this._events, arguments);
        };

        this.Events.trigger = (eventName: string, ...args: any[]): any {
            this._events.trigger.apply(this._events, arguments);
        };

        this.Events.off = (events?: string, callback?: any) : any {
            if (typeof events === 'string' && typeof callback === 'function') {
                this._events.off.call(this._events, events, callback);
            } else if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                this._events.off.call(this._events, callback);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

[image: screenshot of red squiggly]
[image: compilation screenshots]
[image: compilation screenshots]
[image: compilation screenshots]

Am I blindly missing something obvious here?

Comment: Works fine in the TypeScript playground... what's before it? (Or is that not necessarily the same TypeScript version or something?)

Comment: Your posted code has `callback?: any`. The screenshot code has `callback?: (event: any) => any` While both look correct to me, they are different. Hard to tell what else we are missing.

Comment: Perhaps there's an unmatched `(` in the unposted code?

Comment: @JanDvorak I've updated the post. You can post this in the playground and there are no squiggles. However, I created a new typescript file in VS2012 using 0.8.0.0 and it errors.

Comment: What _is_ what you want, then? If that's not code what your code currently says then we cannot ascertain it from said code any more than your interpreter can. We can use human intuition to guess, but...

Comment: When I said "isnt what I want" I just meant how adding that extra `)`  wraps the function in a self-executing one. When that happens it ruins the scope of this.

Comment: @ryan just adding a right parenthesis does not make a function self-executing (or even immediately invoked). Adding `()` does.

Comment: Is the screenshot code a part of a function call (of a function that calls its last argument)? Note that an assignment within an argument list is a bad practice.

Comment: I know that. TypeScript compiles it to an anonymous function. I'll post more screenshots of what is happening in VS.

Comment: How backbone is a part of context? You've got to try and narrow your question to a specific thing.

Answer (score 3):

In the screenshot code, you need either a 'function' keyword or a fat arrow after the parameter list.

Comment: Could you post the valid code snippet without using the function keyword?

Comment: I did originally try to use the function keyword but when it does it trashes the correct context of this. http://i.imgur.com/v5XN7.png - notice how in the other methods `_this` is used but when the function keyboard is used it uses plain `this` instead

Comment: Please consider using gist https://gist.github.com/ or a similar service to share text that people can actually work with, rather than screenshots.

Comment: @ryan if the function keyword is ruining your lexical scope (i.e. this) use the fat arrow syntax Ryan C suggested: ()=> {}

Comment: I couldn't seem to get the syntax right. `this.Events.off = (events?: string, callback?: (event:  any) => any) : any => {` ?